# Is there a way to extract a single number from a double variable in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, binary, counter

I have a program that writes 0's to all digital ports of an external data acquisition device. I am able to access these binary values either 0 or 1 written to the ports as tables in the workspace variables. Then I place each of the bits from each of the tables into a single table. Therefore if each table had a 0 written to the port then, the single 1x4 table would display 0 0 0 0. My goal is to be able to create a binary counter that after inputting all 0's to the ports, then the program would count up to 15 in decimal which would be equivalent to counting from Binary 0000 to Binary 1111.

Currently I converted the table array with all 0's to a double array. Next I converted the double array 0 0 0 0 separated in cells to a single number 0 located in a single cell. Then I can add/increment the value since it is not a table and it returns a 1.Then I convert this decimal number to a binary number which equates to 0001 which is 1 in decimal notation. My question would be how would I extract each number from the binary number which is found in a single cell and then write it to the existing table for each of the ports.

If there is an alternative or any advice on this please let me know it would be of great help, thank you!

Attached is my entire code below:

```
BDaq = NET.addAssembly('Automation.BDaq');
deviceDescription = 'USB-5801,BID#0'; 
startPort = int16(0);  % Writing data to Port 0 
portCount = int16(4);  %Writing digital data up to a certain number of Ports



instantDoCtrl = Automation.BDaq.InstantDoCtrl();

    instantDoCtrl.SelectedDevice = Automation.BDaq.DeviceInformation(deviceDescription);
   %data = NET.createArray('System.Byte', int16(32));
   data = NET.createArray('System.Byte', portCount);
   
 errorcode =  instantDoCtrl.Read(startPort, portCount, data);

    fileout = 'DataA.csv';

        % open output file 
    fid=fopen(fileout,'w');  %Data is not appended

    for i = 0:(portCount - 1)
        fprintf('Input a bit value for Port %d',...
            startPort + i);


        strData = input('(for example, 0 or 1)\n', 's'); %Input in a binary number
         strData = System.String(strData);
        strData = bin2dec(char(strData));      
         data.Set(i, strData); 

   
 fprintf(fid,'Port %d: %8f ',i, data.Get(i));
  % fprintf('Port %d: %8f ',i, data.Get(i))
 
%    
    disp('Digital output completed!');

  
%     % Read back the DO status.
% 
    end

    %Data Written to Ports


    filename = 'C:\Users\kevin\OneDrive - Stony Brook University\Documents\USB-5801\DataA.csv';
    formatSpec = '%4s%3s%9s%5s%3s%9s%5s%3s%9s%5s%3s%9s%s%[^\n\r]';
    fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
    dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', '', 'WhiteSpace', '', 'TextType', 'string',  'ReturnOnError', false);

dataArray{1} = strtrim(dataArray{1});
dataArray{4} = strtrim(dataArray{4});
dataArray{7} = strtrim(dataArray{7});
dataArray{10} = strtrim(dataArray{10});
dataArray{13} = strtrim(dataArray{13});

fclose(fileID);


raw = repmat({''},length(dataArray{1}),length(dataArray)-1);
for col=1:length(dataArray)-1
    raw(1:length(dataArray{col}),col) = mat2cell(dataArray{col}, ones(length(dataArray{col}), 1));
end
numericData = NaN(size(dataArray{1},1),size(dataArray,2));

for col=[2,3,5,6,8,9,11,12]
    % Converts text in the input cell array to numbers. Replaced non-numeric text with NaN.
    rawData = dataArray{col};
    for row=1:size(rawData, 1)
        % Create a regular expression to detect and remove non-numeric prefixes and suffixes.
        regexstr = '(?<prefix>.*?)(?<numbers>([-]*(\d+[\,]*)+[\.]{0,1}\d*[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1})|([-]*(\d+[\,]*)*[\.]{1,1}\d+[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1}))(?<suffix>.*)';
        try
            result = regexp(rawData(row), regexstr, 'names');
            numbers = result.numbers;

            % Detected commas in non-thousand locations.
            invalidThousandsSeparator = false;
            if numbers.contains(',')
                thousandsRegExp = '^[-/+]*\d+?(\,\d{3})*\.{0,1}\d*$';
                if isempty(regexp(numbers, thousandsRegExp, 'once'))
                    numbers = NaN;
                    invalidThousandsSeparator = true;
                end
            end
            % Convert numeric text to numbers.
            if ~invalidThousandsSeparator
                numbers = textscan(char(strrep(numbers, ',', '')), '%f');
                numericData(row, col) = numbers{1};
                raw{row, col} = numbers{1};
            end
        catch
            raw{row, col} = rawData{row};
        end
    end
end


rawNumericColumns = raw(:, [2,3,5,6,8,9,11,12]);
rawStringColumns = string(raw(:, [1,4,7,10,13]));

DataA = table;
DataA.Port = rawStringColumns(:, 1);
DataA.VarName2 = cell2mat(rawNumericColumns(:, 1));
DataA.PortName0 = cell2mat(rawNumericColumns(:, 2));
DataA.Port1 = rawStringColumns(:, 2);
DataA.VarName5 = cell2mat(rawNumericColumns(:, 3));
DataA.PortName1 = cell2mat(rawNumericColumns(:, 4));
DataA.Port2 = rawStringColumns(:, 3);
DataA.VarName8 = cell2mat(rawNumericColumns(:, 5));
DataA.PortName2 = cell2mat(rawNumericColumns(:, 6));
DataA.Port3 = rawStringColumns(:, 4);
DataA.VarName11 = cell2mat(rawNumericColumns(:, 7));
DataA.PortName3 = cell2mat(rawNumericColumns(:, 8));
DataA.VarName13 = rawStringColumns(:, 5);



    A = DataA;   %Data placed in table after assinging bits to Ports
    Portname1 = A(:,1:2);   %Provides Port number 0
    Port1 = A(1,3);         %Provides bit assigned to the digital Port 0
    Portname2 = A(:,4:5);   %Provides Port number 1
    Port2 = A(1,6);         %Provides bit assigned to the digital Port 1
    Portname3 = A(:,7:8);   %Provides Port number 2
    Port3 = A(1,9);         %Provides bit assigned to the digital Port 2
    Portname4 = A(:,10:11);   %Provides Port number 3
    Port4 = A(1,12);         %Provides bit assigned to the digital Port 3


%4 bit Counter for Digital Outputs

Initial = A{:,[3 6 9 12]}; %Input all 0's for Digital Output Ports

if  Initial == 0   %If all 0's are entered perform if task

 Sequence1 = [Port1 Port2 Port3 Port4];  %0 0 0 0

 Port1_cell = table2array(Sequence1);  %Places the bit of the ports from a table into a double variable

Y = str2num(strrep(num2str(Port1_cell), ' ', ''))  %Converts the double variable into a single number

A1 = Y +1;   %increments the number
D1 = dec2bin(A1,4)   %Displays as binary value
```

Comment: "the binary number which is found in a single cell" It is not clear to me how your data is represented in MATLAB. Please post a [mre] that shows how your data is represented. How are you converting numbers, and why would  you "convert" to binary format when all numbers are stored in binary format internally? Are you familiar with MATLAB's [bitwise operators](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/bit-wise-operations.html)?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! The binary number is represented as a 1x4 char variable. Above In my post I edited it to show the main parts of the code where towards the bottom shows the conversions I perform. I am familiar with bitwise operators, however I would like the program to essentially be a binary counter, so i was thinking if I can convert the binary number to a decimal then i can just increment it and  after each increment I can convert the decimal number. I only want to write 0's or 1's to the ports so I  have to convert the decimal to binary

Comment: Are you asking how to convert an integer to its numeric binary representation (rather than the string that `dec2bin` returns)? If so, try `de2bi`, or the newer `int2bit`.

Comment: The commands de2bi or int2bit do not work for me therefore I used dec2bin to convert decimal to binary and I checked it because the Y1 in my code returns 1 which after incrmenting the binary # 0000 adding 1 reveals 0001 which is what the variable D1 shows. I wanted to extract the individual values from the entire binary #. Ex) 0010 is binary number, then I woudl like to place 0 in Port1 then 0 in Port2 then 1 in Port3 and lastly 0 in Port4. I am not sure if this is possible or if another method needs to be considered.

Comment: It is possible, but it's a very roundabout way of doing things. It is better to use `bitset` and `bitget` directly on the numeric value. Is `A` really a `table` object? That seems very inefficient. In any case, you can build `Sequence1` with `DataA(:, 3:3:12)`. Also, `Y = str2num(...)` doesn't give you the number you need, you probably want to do `Y = bin2dec(...)`.

Comment: My task was to increment the counter and therefore I am unable to use bitset/bitget. A is a 1x13 table with Portname, Port#, and bit written to Port, shown separately in each column up to 4 ports. Thank you for the commands, I will utilize them.

Comment: Wow, the DataA(:, 3:3:12) command created the bits for each port in sequence order like a counter, however how would I store each Sequence into all of the ports or are they automatically stored in the Ports? Also if I would like to have a delay for each sequence so that when it is displayed it can be seen if the signal is low or high, how would I incorporate that with the tables that were made. It seems that the 1x4 tables created with the DataA(:, 3:3:12) command show the correct sequence but the column names are not what they should be. The bin2dec provided me with an error (due to table).

Comment: I think you’re confusing a lot of different things, take it one step at a time. Also, looking at the updated code, I’m surprised at you using NET for anything. `bitset` and `bitget` is exactly what you should be using, you can tweak individual bits of an integer value (or an array of them). If you read and write individual bits, but you want them to represent a single integer, you use those functions to set/get the individual bits of the single integer.

Comment: Regarding NET I am unfamiliar with it but for matlab examples that I found after installing the driver for the Advantech USB-5801 data module device it uses it and therefore I wasn't sure fo another way to communicate with this device without NET objects. Can I ask what is the difference between bitset and lets say setting the port to a 1 or a 0 using an assignment operator?